# Can't select text within the question title

Tags: discussion, questions, title

[The question title links to itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47653/why-does-the-question-title-link-to-itself-on-the-answer-page) but that makes it impossible to select text within the title any longer. In the screenshot below I was trying to select "Messageformat" for later entry in a package lookup query.

[image]

The solution is to select the entire text starting from outside the title, copy it, paste it in some editor, then edit to only the text you want. This is way more cumbersome than having to click the browser's refresh button (or Cmd+R/F5) instead of the question title. Does linking the question to itself save time overall?

Comment: It's a common thing, I use it a lot e.g. when viewing specific answer or comment I want to get back to the question itself. Without direct link in title I'll have to manually change the URL.

Comment: Anyway, simple workaround is editing the question then you can select anything you want from the textbox. (thinking about it, small "edit title" link would be useful same way we have "edit tags" above certain rep :))

Comment: @3ventic: smartasspoints += 100. Better link people to [how to select text in links](https://superuser.com/questions/173200/how-to-select-hyperlink-text-in-google-chrome).

Comment: @DanDascalescu Sorry, showing it on video that I could create in a matter of seconds seemed more helpful than googling for an existing resource.

Comment: On MSO: [Can titles be made more select-friendly?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306193/4642212).

Answer (score 10):

Assuming Windows, hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while selecting text that are also links, it's a standard browser feature. See [How to Select Hyperlink Text in Google Chrome?](//superuser.com/q/173200):

> Pressing ALT while selecting text prevents hyperlinks being followed, and therefore allows all or partial text in links to be selected and copied.

This applies, at least, to both Firefox and Chrome.

- On Macs, use the <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> key.
- On Linux, use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>

*(Originally posted to a [similar question on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373848/100297))*

Comment: On Linux, alt+drag&drop moves the window.

Comment: @DanDascalescu: That behaviour is actually specific to your *window manager*. On KDE I think that `Super`+`Alt` should work to select the text. See [How to select (& copy) only a part (in the middle) of a linked text?](//askubuntu.com/q/282336) and [this comment on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/583795/how-to-select-copy-only-a-part-of-a-linked-text#comment716398_583801).  `Super` is usually the key with the Windows logo on it.

Comment: Super+Alt worked, thanks!

Comment: I came to meta to rant about how inconvenient it is to make title a link, but found an [unexpected](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Law_of_Surprise) life-changer feature...

Comment: Alt + left click drag also moves the window on [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)) (e.g., with [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa)) and Firefox. Win + Alt + left click drag works.