# How do I select the title of a SE question? (Select by click-drag in browser)

Tags: support

How do I select the title of a question using click+drag in the browser? (As the first step before hitting `^C` to copy the title to clipboard.)

It doesn't work to click on the title itself (where you get the "hand" icon) and it also doesn't work to click next to the title (left or right) (where you get the "arrow" icon).

- I'm sure this used to work very naturally, without much difficulty in picking where to click initially ...
- I tried two SE sites: SO, and Retrocomputing.  Same (mis)behavior in both.

  - Oddly, it seems possible (though very finicky to pick the click target) here at `meta.stackexchange.com`
- Browser today is Chrome 91.0.4472.101

Comment: Clicking right after the title and dragging works fine for me. Alternatively, you could do a triple-click.

Comment: `Alt`+`Click` and drag should work. You can also start dragging from a few pixels above or below the title.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+select+part+of+title) of [Can't select text within the question title](/q/248065/289905). On MSO: [Can titles be made more select-friendly?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306193/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon - I'll look into both your suggestions, thank you!

Comment: `Alt`+`Click` is especially useful when you want to select part of the title (e.g., in the middle). However, both dragging from the right and triple-clicking work just fine for selecting the entire title [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrHVV.gif). Not sure if it's a browser issue but I'm also using Chrome (on Windows).

Comment: Alt + left click drag doesn't work by default in [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)) (e.g., with [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa)) and Firefox - the entire window is dragged instead. The window is also brought out of maximised mode (if it is maximised). OK, Win + Alt + left click drag works, as in [the duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248065/cant-select-text-within-the-question-title).