# Clickable title of the question

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, title

Every question on every Stack Exchange site being opened has a title, [e.g](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287606/339911):

> [image: title]

This title is clickable. What kind of benefits gives clickable title here?

Answer (score 2):

For me it has several benefits:

- Refresh the page;
- Remove the anchor to a comment or answer if I want to refresh the page;
- Use that link to share the question (I am aware of the share button, but you actually don't always want to use it).

Comment: Could you clarify the second option, please?

Comment: Open the comment link (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290522/clickable-title-of-the-question#comment943210_290523), when you now refresh the page it keeps going to the comment. If you want to go to the question instead, click the link.

Comment: Now I see, thanx.